# iOS - Programatically extracting a silhouette from a bitmap

Tags: ios, image-processing, opencv, imagemagick

I'm investigating the possibility of creating a b&w silhouette picture from a bitmap (from a photo taken on an iOS device's camera), of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFlEu.png) type.

I've done some Googling and come up with a lot of links about ImageMagick, CoreImages and OpenCV but I have some difficulty evaluating how hard it would be to do so and what the steps would be.

Is it a feasible goal to with maximum a few weeks development generate a similar silhouette from a carefully taken photo using the users device?

Pointers to known processes/algorithms would of course be extra helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On an iDevice yes but only if the photo is of the user against a very light/uniformly colored background.

If that's not the case, you're going to need to do a LOT more work to achieve this goal.

If the user is against a relatively lightly colored background that's uniform in color. You should be able to get the basic idea of what you're looking for my playing with the whitepoint/gamma and brightness/contrast to sort of flush out a darker area where the person is. If you process from there, you should be able to detect an "outline" of that shape and use those figures to re-draw your silhouette from there.

Comment: Just want to add that [thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) should get you a long way

Comment: Yupper ;) that's basically where he'd have to take it, but first he'd have to use gamma/saturation/brightness/contrast/etc to refine the i-device photo to a point where you could reliably threshold the photo into two pieces like that :)